# Text Watcher android in on create

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

I have been trying to use textwatcher.
i called the function addTextChangedListener(this) , from onCreate but the application crashed because of this command.
please help .

```
private EditText txt1; 
private EditText txt2;
private EditText txt3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);



     txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
     txt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
     txt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
    txt1.addTextChangedListener(this);
    txt2.addTextChangedListener(this);
    txt3.addTextChangedListener(this);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

And :

```
@Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    int id = view.getId();
    if (id == R.id.signup_username) {
        String username = ((EditText) view).getText().toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < username.length(); i++) {
            if (username.charAt(i) < 'a' || username.charAt(i) > 'z') {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Murad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oren", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

log:

```
04-03 11:37:22.684: D/skia(23439): new locale en-Latn-GB
04-03 11:37:22.854: D/libEGL(23439): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
04-03 11:37:22.854: D/libEGL(23439): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
04-03 11:37:22.864: D/libEGL(23439): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
04-03 11:37:22.864: I/Adreno-EGL(23439): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
04-03 11:37:22.864: I/Adreno-EGL(23439): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
04-03 11:37:22.864: I/Adreno-EGL(23439): Build Date: 09/26/13 Thu
04-03 11:37:22.864: I/Adreno-EGL(23439): Local Branch: 
04-03 11:37:22.864: I/Adreno-EGL(23439): Remote Branch: 
04-03 11:37:22.864: I/Adreno-EGL(23439): Local Patches: 
04-03 11:37:22.864: I/Adreno-EGL(23439): Reconstruct Branch: 
04-03 11:37:22.914: D/OpenGLRenderer(23439): Enabling debug mode 0
04-03 11:37:39.971: D/AndroidRuntime(23439): Shutting down VM
04-03 11:37:39.971: W/dalvikvm(23439): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b2b898)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.poca2/com.example.poca2.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at com.example.poca2.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:33)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
04-03 11:37:39.981: E/AndroidRuntime(23439):    ... 11 more
04-03 11:37:44.545: D/skia(23761): new locale en-Latn-GB
04-03 11:37:44.776: D/libEGL(23761): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
04-03 11:37:44.786: D/libEGL(23761): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
04-03 11:37:44.786: D/libEGL(23761): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
04-03 11:37:44.786: I/Adreno-EGL(23761): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
04-03 11:37:44.786: I/Adreno-EGL(23761): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
04-03 11:37:44.786: I/Adreno-EGL(23761): Build Date: 09/26/13 Thu
04-03 11:37:44.786: I/Adreno-EGL(23761): Local Branch: 
04-03 11:37:44.786: I/Adreno-EGL(23761): Remote Branch: 
04-03 11:37:44.786: I/Adreno-EGL(23761): Local Patches: 
04-03 11:37:44.786: I/Adreno-EGL(23761): Reconstruct Branch: 
04-03 11:37:44.836: D/OpenGLRenderer(23761): Enabling debug mode 0
04-03 11:37:48.069: D/AndroidRuntime(23761): Shutting down VM
04-03 11:37:48.069: W/dalvikvm(23761): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b2b898)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.poca2/com.example.poca2.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at com.example.poca2.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:33)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
04-03 11:37:48.069: E/AndroidRuntime(23761):    ... 11 more
04-03 11:37:54.265: I/Process(23761): Sending signal. PID: 23761 SIG: 9
```

edit:

```
private EditText txt1; 
private EditText txt2;
private EditText txt3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);



    txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_username);
    txt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_password);
    txt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_email);
    txt1.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(txt1, getApplicationContext()));
    txt2.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(txt2, getApplicationContext()));
    txt3.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(txt3, getApplicationContext()));
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

}
 class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
EditText m;
Context c;
public CustomTextWatcher (EditText e, Context context) {
    m = e;
    c = context;
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int id = m.getId();
    if (id == R.id.signup_username) {
        String username = ((EditText) m).getText().toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < username.length(); i++) {
            if (username.charAt(i) < 'a' || username.charAt(i) > 'z') {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Murad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(c, "Oren", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

here is the edited edition.

Comment: You need an instance of TextWatcher class, where are you creating it?. Post your StackTrace

Comment: i have added the log. i didn't created an instance of TextWatcher , i've implement TextWAtcher.

Comment: you have to put your beforeTextChanged() , onTextChanged() , afterTextChanged() in a TextWatche object.

Comment: if ill create new class that implements textwatcher, how can i know which item has been edited/pressed ?

Comment: @user3492773 Log.d the value of getCurrentFocus();

Comment: ok, i created CustomTextWatcher class, and everytime i called addTextChangedListner i call it like - addTextChangedListner(new CustomTextWatcher(myEditText)).
but now i cant use Toast, beacuse getApplicationContext is undefinded

Comment: notify the user about illegal inputs!

Comment: Are your edittexts really in activity_register layout and not in the placeholder fragment layout?

Comment: @user3492773 you dont need CustomTextWatcher you can implement TextWatcher in your Activity for example

Comment: edittext is in register_fragment.
i tried to implment textwatcher in the activity, but when i added the listner to the edittext in onCreate, the app crashed hen activity is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EditText`s are not in the `activity_register` layout but in the fragment and thus cannot be found with `findViewById()` after inflating only the `activity_register` layout. This causes the NPE when you're attempting to invoke a method on a null reference.

Move the `findViewById()` and `addTextChangedListener()` code to the fragment's `onCreateView()` where you're actually inflating the view that contains the edittexts.